# Conjugacy between subgroup and group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$, a finite group. Show that there exists $x\in G$
>   which is not conjugate to an element of $H$.

**Attempt:** let $G$ act on $X$, the set of all proper groups of $G$, by conjugation. We have: $$|G|=|\text{Orb}(H)||\text{Stab}(H)|\geq |\text{Orb}(H)||H|\quad (h\in H\Rightarrow h\in \text{Stab}(H))$$
(*ignore from here*) Since $H$ is a proper subgroup:

$$2\leq |G/H|\leq |\text{Orb}(H)|$$
We can write $\text{Orb}(H)=\{H, g_1Hg_1^{-1},\;\dots ,\;g_nHg_n^{-1}\}$ where $n\geq 1$. I feel like this is close but need a little push to see what to do next, or maybe a hint if I am going in the wrong direction. Any help appreciated.

Comment: When $G$ acts on its set of subgroups by conjugation, the stabilizer of $H$ is called the *normalizer* of $H$, and can be strictly bigger than $H$ itself. So you can't replace ${\rm Stab}(H)$ with $H$.

Comment: Are you working with finite groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for finite groups.

**proof:**  Since number of the the conjugate of $H$ equal to $|G:N_G(H)|\leq|G:H|$ and every conjugate of $H$ has same order with $H$ and $H^g\cap H $ is nonempty set for all $g\in G$.

Thus, their union can not equal to $G$ as $|G|=|H||G:H|\geq |H||G:N_G(H)|$. We are done.

Comment: I will change the word "with " as an "and".

Comment: OK, I agree now, though I think you mean that  $H$ has the same order as $H^{g}$ for all $g \in G.$